# servicestack read from web.config fails in production build

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config, servicestack

I need to read values from web.config

```
IAppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();

        var slackWebHookUrl = appSettings.Get<string>("slackWebHookUrl");
```

in dev conditions it works. But after I run dotnet publish and try start app it no longer can provide values from web.config

Comment: _"it no longer can provide values from web.config"_ - how did you determine that? Does it throw an exception, does it return null, or does something else happen? Chances are your deployed configuration file simply doesn't contain that key.

Comment: no exceptions. it returns empty string. and there is web.config with all keys in it. so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure the App has read permissions to read web.config.

ServiceStack infers the path to web.config using:

```
var webConfigPath = Platform.Instance.GetAppConfigPath();
```

Make sure it can be read with:

```
var xml = File.ReadAllText(webConfigPath);
```